# Python: better way to open lots of sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I have the following program to open lot's of sockets, and hold them open to stress test one of our servers.  There are several problem's with this.  I think it could be a lot more efficient than a recursive call, and it's really still opening sockets in a serial fashion rather than parallel fashion.  I realize there are tools like ab that could probably simulate what I'm trying to do, but I'm hoping to increase my python knowledge.  Is this something I should be rewriting as either multi-threaded or multi-process?

```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> 
> import socket, time, sys
> sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
> 
> def open_socket(counter):   
>   sockname = "s" + str(counter)   
>   port = counter + 3000   
>   sockname = socket.socket()  
>   sockname.bind(('localhost', port))  
>   sockname.listen(1)   
>   if counter == 2:
>     time.sleep(20)   
>   elif counter > 2:
>     counter = counter -1
>     open_socket(counter)
> 
> open_socket(1500)
```

Comment: just listening and no accept?

Comment: I didn't know for sure that I needed an accept().  Would I get FIN_WAIT messages in netstat output if I didn't add conn,addr = sockname.accept()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was puzzled why you would use recursion instead of a simple loop. My guess is that with a simple loop, you would have overwritten the variable sockname again and again, so that Python's garbage collection would actually close the previous socket after you created the next one. The solution is to store them all in a list, to prevent Python from garbage-collecting them:

```
def open_socket(counter):
  sockets = []
  for i in range(counter):
     s = socket.socket()
     s.bind(('localhost', i+3000))
     s.listen(1)
     sockets.append(s)
  time.sleep(20)
```

Also notice that in your code, the first assignment to sockname is completely redundant, as it is overwritten by the second assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Twisted for this. It greatly simplifies networking on Python. Their site has [some tutorials](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/core/documentation/howto/index.html) to get you started.

However, you could easily see using Python an overkill for this task. A faster option to hack up would be to just open 1500 instances of nc:

```
for i in {3000..4500};
do
    nc -l -p $i &
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's already multi process - put a sleep in before calling open_socket, and run , say , 500 of them from a shell:

```
for i in `seq 500`; do ./yourprogram & done
```

You're not a actually connecting to something though - seems you're setting up server sockets ? If you need to connect to something you surly should test it with parallelism(multiple threads, or run many processes like shown above or using asyncronous connect's). [This](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html) should be of interest to read:

Comment: That was an interesting read.  Thanks.  I don't think I will use asyncore for this particular issue, but I think it solves another problem for me.  As far as the code snippet above, I originally had the same logic, accept creating sockets and running socket.connect() in a recursive function.  I'm just really bad at posting questions, so I left some information out, and posted part of the wrong code.  Although the first assignment to sockname was actually to generate enumerated handles to connect.